# Game holds handle to wma file after exit

Tags: .net, xna, filehandle

I have an xna game exported in a dll file. Everything to run the game (except the content) is in this library, especially the main game class.

In another assembly, I load the game dll, instantiate the game class and call `Run()` on it. This will run the game. After that, when the game is closed, I call `Dispose()` to completely close the game. The main program (that, which loaded the dll) is still running.

Up to here, no problems.

However, when the game uses a `Song` with the `MediaPlayer`, it seems that the game is not closed completely. In the content directory of the game, there are the according `.xnb` and `.wma` files for the song. And although the game does not run anymore, I cannot delete the `.wma` file, because a process (my main program) still holds a handle to this file. The `.xnb` file can be deleted without any problems.

I found out that an additional thread is created by the game, which is not closed after the game exits. I suspect this thread to be a media player thread that still holds the file handle. Is there any way to force xna to give up the file handle? Maybe killing the additional thread would be an option (although it is not very nice), but how to do that?

Calling `Stop()` on the `MediaPlayer` does not change this behaviour.

Comment: Do you call `Dispose()` on `Song`?

Comment: No, because it is handled by XNA`s content manager. However, calling `Dispose()` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling Stop() on *every* instance of Song you start?

Comment: Yes. I created a test project with only one song instance, which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the general practice when creating XNA games is to not use the MediaPlayer at all, instead using the Sound & SoundInstance alternative.  Though they may use different sound formats, they are better for performance since MediaPlayer is a huge hog, and in your case, threading issues.

I am probably wrong, but I think MediaPlayer actually calls the local machines actual MediaPlayer.  This might be one of the reasons why it's so hard to stop it's thread.

It's up to you, but I would avoid MediaPlayer entirely.  It's considered a curse to me :D